# Delphi How to Display a cursor image on Timage?

Tags: delphi

i want load .cur file display on Timage.DisPlay as a Image.not setcursor.

i have tryed

```
    var ico:= TIcon.Create;
    var bm:=Tbitmap.Create;
    ico.LoadFromResourceName(Hinstance,'spy_cur');
    ico.AssignTo(bm);

    //Panel6.Brush.Bitmap:=bm;   do not work.
    //Image2.Picture.Bitmap:=bm;  do not work.
    //DrawIconEx(image2.Canvas.Handle,0,0,ico.Handle,32,32,0,0,DI_Normal); do not work.
```

how?

cur file is not ico file.
Image2.Picture.Bitmap:=bm; not work.
image2.Picture.Graphic:=ico; not work.

Comment: One answer suggested on Telegram: https://t.me/delphidevelopers/30141

const
  crCustomCursor = 10;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.Cursors[crCustomCursor] := LoadCursorFromFile('path/to/your/cursor.cur');
  Image1.Cursor := crCustomCursor;
end;

Comment: ico.AssignTo(bm);  Image2.Picture.Bitmap:=bm;  This dos not work!ico is not similie cur file

Answer (score 1):

[TImage](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TImage) component has a [Picture](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TImage.Picture) property which is a reference to a [TPicture](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPicture) object which contains many methods for working with graphics.

One of the most usefull methods amongst them is [Assign](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPicture.Assign) which allows you to assign any compatible Graphic object to the TPicture class. Assign method determines what graphic obet you are trying to assign automatically.

So in your case the code for showing an icon on TImage would be as simple as this:

```
ico:= TIcon.Create;
ico.LoadFromResourceName(Hinstance,'spy_cur');
Image1.Picture.Assign(ico);
```

EDIT: If you have icons stored as individual files you can even load them to your image with `Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('MyIconFile.ico');`. So no need to use `TIcon` class in such scenario.

PS: If you want to show some other image types like PNG or JPEG you may need to add respective units for working with those image types into uses section.The `VCL.Graphics` unit contains needed code for just some of the available image types.

And yes there are 3rd party libraries that you can add to your program in order to add support for many more image types.

EDIT2: I overlooked that you are trying to show cursor resource. In order to load cursor resource to Icon you need to use code like tihs:

```
var ico: TIcon;
var HCursor: THandle;

ico := TIcon.Create;
HCursor := LoadCursor(hInstance,'spy_cur');
//Since LoadCursor does not raise any Exception wee need to check 
//if cursor was loaded by our self and if not retrieve the last 
//error message
if HCursor = 0 then
begin
  MessageDlg(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError),mtError,[mbOK],0);
end;
ico.Handle := HCursor;
Image1.Picture.Assign(ico);
```

PS: When I try this on a new Delphi application I get the error that specific resource can not be found. So I'm guessing you are probably adding custom cursor resources to your application.

Comment: `Image1.Picture.Graphic := ico;` also works, too. It has the same effect as `Image1.Picture.Assign(ico);`

Comment: i said it dos not work.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide the code for loading cursor resource